# Unable to boot while installing Ubuntu 18.04 in VirtualBox in HP

Tags: boot, system-installation

I am Unable to install Ubuntu in Oracle VirtualBox in *Windows 10*.
I Have already enabled Virtualization in the boot menu...

While trying to install, I get the following error:

> This kernel requires an x86-64 CPU, but only detected an i686 CPU.
>   Unable to boot - please use a kernel appropriate for your CPU.

[This is a picture of the error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4F30l.png)

What can I do to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Your error indicates that your CPU doesn't support the Intel 64-bit ISA.
You can't fix this with a software update, you're gonna need a hardware upgrade to a CPU with 64-bit support.

**My personal recommendation is:**
Upgrade to a 64-bit architecture with IOMMU support. Then you will be able to do full *Hardware Virtualization* and *IO-Virtualization* as well. So check the spec sheets of your preferred MB + CPU vendors.

Your only alternative would be using a full x64 processor emulation, but I don't know of any.